# difference between special price and actual price

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have configurable product with special price ,i want to show the difference of special price and actual price of this product and the difference will change on change of the option selection

Answer (score 1):

1. **Price** - the price at which you want to sell the product; this is the only required field here and, of course, the most important
2. **Cost** - this represents your cost for purchasing the product
3. **Tier Price** - through this option you can set discounts based on the quantity of products purchased
4. **Special Price** - through this option you can set promotional campaigns - discounts which are valid only within the period defined in Special Price From Date and Special Price To Date; this option is not affected by the quantity of purchased products